# bootstrap modal $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a bootstrap modal dialog when clicking the span, I've searched the internet for solutions to my problem ***bootstrap modal $(...).modal is not a function*** but the only solution I've found is " put jQuery scripts before bootstrap scripts because bootstrap depends on jQuery " so I've put jQuery first, and it still gives me the same error: ***bootstrap modal $(...).modal is not a function***

Here's the code I've tried with so far:

**HTML**

```
<span value="${bean.getId(i)}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove spanRemoveTransaction" style="color:red; cursor: pointer; margin-top:8px;" nowrap="true" data-toggle="myModal" data-target="#modal"></span>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".spanRemoveTransaction").on('click', function (e) {
    theTransactionId = $(this).attr("value");
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteTransactionModal(theTransactionId, e);
});

function deleteTransactionModal(theTransactionId, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#myModal').modal({
        keyboard: false
    }).on('click', '#delete', function (e) {
        var url = config.deploymentIp + "/Controller?deleteTransaction";
        var transactionId = "";
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {transactionId: theTransactionId},
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if (!data["has_errors"]) {
                    $('table#transactionList tr#'+theTransactionId).remove();
                } else {
                    transactionId = data.errors["transactionId"];

                    if (transactionId === "transactionIdError") {

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Scripts**

```
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/selectpicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/currencyExchange.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/atbottom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/loadBottomScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/menuScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/transfers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If anyone has a solution to this, or just happen to have fresh eyes and can help me locate the problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check in your browser `script` is rendering or not

Comment: Why do you have `jQuery.noConflict();` right before calling the `.modal()` method?

Comment: Could it be that your loaded bootstrap.js version doesn't include modal.js

Comment: You have a missing `}` to close the second function, I assume, you just did not copy out the whole script.

Comment: edited, still not working though - @karasci_maci yes, that was a misscopy, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Flyer53 It does have modal v3.3.4 included

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `jQuery.noCoflict`

Here is a **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r96ttcqn/)**

Use

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery('#myModal') ....
```

Please tell me if it works or not.

**UPDATE**

As @dashtinejad point to another thing in his comment after the no conflict:

Other parts of script which rely on `$` should change to `jQuery` also

Comment: Other parts of script which rely on `$` should change to `jQuery` also.

Comment: it's so weird because it works in the fiddle, and when i grab what's in the fiddle and put it in my app, i have the same problem as before

Comment: Check console for errors, after  you rewrite the `$` to `jQuery`.  Use your code, not from fiddle, I copied yours to fidle :)

Then maybe some of your other script conflicts. Try comment them one by one, and realod the page. Or create a blank page only with the necessary scripts and css.

Comment: You could use this `$ = jQuery.noConflict();` and have not to replace all `$` with `jQuery` anymore.

Comment: it's very interesting, if i put $('#dummyModal').modal(); in document ready for example, it will appear when i load the page. but if i put the same piece of code inside a function, which indeed is in document ready aswell, it doesn't appear... I'm lost

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

     // Attach Button click event listener 
    $('.glyphicon-remove spanRemoveTransaction').click(function(){

         // show Modal
      alert("pp")
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<span value="${bean.getId(i)}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove spanRemoveTransaction" style="color:red; cursor: pointer; margin-top:8px;" nowrap="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">click the span</span>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```